# How does the CPU know where to look for a given physical memory address?

Tags: cpu, memory-address, bios

If I understand correctly, whenever a CPU is turned on it jumps to a manufacturer hardwired default physical memory address and starts executing the binary code present there. Naturally in a PC the default location maps to the ROM containing the BIOS.

Suppose I have a system with RAM installed as well, how does the CPU know that it is supposed to search for that specific address in the ROM chip containing the BIOS and not RAM's address?

Do the manufacturers of the Motherboard and the RAM have some standard or contract where they agree that the memory addresses of their hardware will never overlap?

Comment: I apologize if my low level understanding of this is skewed. I would greatly appreciate your clarification.

Comment: Why have you tagged this "embedded systems" while you talk about motherboards and BIOS? A PC is not an embedded system.

Comment: the CPU doesnt know or care, the cpu strictly does what the instructions tell it to do.  The memory/data bus(es) on the edge of the cpu project those requests, and the logic beyond that determines who is being talked to.  The post(wo)man doesnt care one bit about one address or another, they just sort the mail and deliver it to the right place based on what is written on it.  The cpu doesnt care it delivers the message to the bus, the memory controller sorts those requests and delivers them to the right peripheral or memory.

Comment: Just like a developer would be wise not to have two houses with the same address, a board/chip designer would not have two targets that answer to the same address, although on chips/boards we do that all the time but we do it in a priority way, if the l1 cache has the answer, it answers, if it doesnt it asks the l2 and so on.  Kind of like having your mail held at the post office for a while until you can get to it later.

Answer (score 0):

I think you will see this diagram very often:

[image]

It summarize several things (I assumed you are familiar with the definition of "Physical Addresses" and "Virtual Addresses":

1. All program and wires within the CPU, always communicate and exchange among themselves "virtual addresses".   You will never encounter any "physical addresses".
2. To address any DRAM outside the CPU, you will need "physical addresses".
3. The same "virtual addresses", can map to different "physical addresses".  Eg, the following instruction:

load eax, (virtual_address_XXXX)  (load from memory into EAX)

Same assembly instruction, but running under different processes, will result in accessing different parts of physical memory.   (this is done through pagetable + MMU)

4. Translation from virtual address to physical address will need the MMU.   Any electrical signals detected outside the CPU, is always at the physical addresses level.   So all hardware devices (eg, memory) have to recognize that.

[image]

https://www.slideserve.com/stacie/computer-architecture-memory-management-units

So to start off, your question in the "title" is not really correct - the CPU does not know and see any "physical addresses", it is the hardware devices.   But all get translated by the MMU (or IOMMU) (can cached by the TLB).

Note that some CPU does not have MMU.    So "physical" and also the same value as "virtual address".

Answer (score -1):

Let us take it step by step in a quick way:
When you reset your PC, it actually runs the code from BIOS.
Bios code is code written by Motherboard manufacturer to boot up the board. Then and after Bios finish its job. MBR; Master Boot Record, will run it is a piece of code written at the head of your HDD (address 0) when you installed you operating system, say windows or Linux.
This piece of code is responsible for jumping to your windows drive to start it which is called bootloader. So,

BIOS(Non-Volatile Memory) -> MBR(HDD) -> OS

If you think about it, you can find that there is an option of booting sequence inside BIOS to identify which is MBR should be read from HDD, DVD, ...etc

Read more about BIOS:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BIOS

Read more about MBR:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Master_boot_record